Remove "Link" or "New Note" Item from Right Click Menus
I have been able to hide most other context menu options such as "Insert" or "Delete" etc. But there area  few that I cannot seem to get rid of and I am starting to wonder if it is not possible.
Under normal circumstances, when right clicking on a cell in Excel you get a shortcut menu. I have been using VBA in Excel to remove many of these when the excel workbook activates and restoring them when it closes.
What I have been using to remove them is something like this in a subroutine for example:
Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls("Filter").Visible = False
I can cycle through all of the items in the controls collection and remove them all except for:
-New Comment
-New Note
-Link
It does have a hyperlink item in the collection that I have hidden but it doesn't seem to affect this link option. There also is an insert comment item in the collection but that also does not turn this new comment off.
Any ideas?

It would help if we could test your code, but one line doesn't let us do that.  It's much easier if folks don't need to start from scratch when trying to help answer your question.

Ok let's just say I am trying to remove everything and then manually add back the ones I want. For the sake of argument, I realize it is not the most efficient, but the answer will be helpful to me.

Sub hideitem()     For Each Item In Application.CommandBars("Cell").Controls    'removes all right click menu items         Item.Visible = False     Next Item End Sub

I apologize for not being more clear. And also for not knowing how to format the code in these replies.

Click the "edit" link under your question: if you need to add code it should go in the main post, not as a comment.  Use the {} button to format the code.
